# Convert unsigned char in C to MatLab

Tags: c, matlab, char, unsigned

I am trying to convert unsigned char in C to matlab code, the vector of unsigned char is filled with hexadecimal values. Below the C code:

```
int main()
{
  unsigned char value = 0xaa;
  signed char temp;
  // cast to signed value
  temp = (signed char) value;
  // if MSB is 1, then this will signed extend and fill the temp variable with 1's
  temp = temp >> 7;
  // AND with the reduction variable
  temp = temp & 0x1b;
  // finally shift and reduce the value
  printf("%u",((value << 1)^temp));
}
```

The Matlab function that I create to do the same thing:

```
value = '0xaa';
temp = int8(value);
temp2 = int8(value);
temp = bitsra(temp,7);
temp = and(temp,'0x1b');
galois_value =   xor(bitsll(temp2,1),temp);
disp(galois_value);
```

The values printed are different in each code, someone knows what is happening?

Comment: Note, your C code relies on implementation-defined behaviour;  a well-defined way to do what I assume you intend would be `unsigned int temp = (value > SCHAR_MAX ? 0x1b : 0);`

Comment: That is not the problem, the C code is a library from Texas Instruments to use in MSP430 series MCU. I need to implement the C code in MatLab to compare performance, because of that I can't change the C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a string:

```
value = '0xaa';
```

Of 4 characters, `['0' 'x' 'a' 'a']`.

In MATLAB you don't generally handle variables bit wise, but if you want, try:

```
temp = int8(hex2dec('aa'));
```

Comment: Can I use this to convert an entire vector of char? Like `char = {'aa,bb,cc'}` and then `temp = int8(hex2dec(char));`

Comment: When I print the value in MatLab I always get `11` and the C code gives me `335`, why the `galois_value` variable gets a logical value?

Comment: @IAGOSESTREMOchoa You have a problem: you are trying to translate a program line by line. Do not do that, especially with languages so different. Try to get the same functionality, but using the best methods for each language. The answe to your questions can be solved by reading the documentation of the MATLAB functions.

Comment: I noticed that, but like I said above,  I need to implement the C code in MatLAB to compare performance, because of that the two codes needs to be almost the "same". When I say compare performance it's because I am simulating a Power Line Communication system in MatLAB that uses a texas MCU, the C code is from texas and is not avaliable in MatLAB. The problem now is the `bitsra, and, xor` is returning a logical value and not a integer number like the C code. Should I edit the question to show this?

Comment: Google for "bitwise xor MATLAB" @IAGOSESTREMOchoa ('bitxor')